# Best Practices Standards - SQL query to Laravel Eloquent/Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the following SQL Query which is executing fine.

```
SELECT *, (((product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price)*100) as p_discount
FROM `products`
WHERE product_price IS NOT NULL
  AND (((product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price)*100) > 25
ORDER BY p_discount DESC
```

I want to achieve the same result in LARAVEL best practices standards.

> ```
> Controller: ProductController
> Model: Product
> ```

what i have tried so far is :

```
$discount_range = Config::get('constants.discount_range')[$type];
$products       = Product::whereRaw('product_price IS NOT NULL AND (((product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price)*100) BETWEEN '.$discount_range[0].' AND '.$discount_range[1])->orderBy("product_sell_price", $sort_by)->paginate($perpage);
```

Is there any way i can do something more useful than this. I don't want to use WhereRaw().

Please help me to improve. Thanks :)

Comment: You can't avoid `raw` completely but you can do something like: `whereNotNull('product_price')->where(DB::raw('(product_price-product_sell_price)/product_sell_price)*100)'),  '>', 25)`

Answer (score -1):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use  Model\Product;

Product::select('*',
DB::raw('((product_price - product_sell_price) / product_sell_price)*100 as p_discount')
->where('p_discount', '>', 25)
->whereNotNull('product_price')
->orderBy('p_discount', 'desc')
)->get();

Comment: As I have already mentioned, i want to avoid Raw. i want to do it with best practices standards.